# how do I multiply two tensors and then do a contraction with a third one in Eigen?

Tags: c++, eigen

I want to have an Eigen C++ function that basically looks like:

```
void multiplyAndContract(Tensor& a, Tensor& b, Tensor &c)
```

which simply takes b and c and coordinate-wise multiplies them (they are of the same dimensions) and then contracts a with the result of b and c multiplied (say on the first dimension on both b*c and a).

b and c would generally be of vector dimensions (meaning, a tensor of rank 1).

I am not sure how to do coordinate-wise multiplication with Eigen with tensors (there is no cwiseProduct, it seems, like there is for matrices), and I am also not sure how to do that so that it is the most efficient as far as creating temporary tensors.

I would be happy to get some examples for code, it doesn't have to be fully functional, but just a reference on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `*` operator for coefficient wise multiplication.

```
Tensor a;
Tensor b;
Tensor c;
Eigen::array<Eigen::DenseIndex, 1> contraction_pair;
contraction_pair[0] = Eigen::IndexPair<Index>(0, 0);
Tensor result = (b * c).contract(a, contraction_pair);
```